# getElementById in Safari

Tags: safari, applescript

I want do download my epaper using AppleScript and Safari. Here's my code:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://kundenkonto.mittelbayerische.de/frontend/login.php?service=http://epaper.mittelbayerische.de/edition-mbz/index2.jsp%3Flang%3Dde"}
    delay 5
tell document 1
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('submit_btn').click()"
    delay 5
    do JavaScript "loadEditionPDF();"
end tell
end tell
```

It loads the site, Safari fills in the login credentials automatically, but then it stops at "document.getElementById('submit_btn').click()" with "missing value".

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to go to the childNodes of the element so this will work.

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
make new document with properties {URL:"https://kundenkonto.mittelbayerische.de/frontend/login.php?service=http://epaper.mittelbayerische.de/edition-mbz/index2.jsp%3Flang%3Dde"}
delay 5
tell document 1
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('submit_btn').childNodes[0].click()"
    delay 5
    do JavaScript "loadEditionPDF();"
end tell
end tell
```